Equivalent definitions of affine function: Does $f(\gamma x +(1-\gamma)y)=\gamma f(x)+(1-\gamma)f(y)$ on convex set $S$ imply linearity of $f$ on $S$?
For a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ the following two are equivalent
\begin{align*}
&\text{(i) there exist $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)=a^{t}x+b$}\newline
&\text{(ii) for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma\in(0,1)$ it holds $f(\gamma x +(1-\gamma)y)=\gamma f(x)+(1-\gamma)f(y)$}.
\end{align*}
See for example here for a proof
I want to argue that the statement still holds if we consider functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ where $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set. My intuitive idea: Obviously $(i)\implies (ii)$ still holds in that case. On the other hand, if we assume that (ii) is true, then we could consider the affine space spanned by $X$. Let us call this affine space $Y$. I think it should be true, that the interior of $X$ is open in $Y$. So we could probably define an affine function $\tilde{f}:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ that extends $f$ first. And then extend $\tilde{f}$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (somehow). I am hoping that someone knows how to do this rigorously.

I am not sure about the idea to prove statements about $Y$, since any results that you prove for $Y$ does not necessarily imply results for $X$. One way to prove this, however, would be the following:
Let $d$ be the dimension of the affine space $Y$. Now pick $d+1$ points in the interior of $X$ in general position (no $k+2$ points in the same $k$-dimensional affine space). Call them $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_{d+1}$. Their convex hull is a simplex. From (ii) we can derive that the value of $f$ in the simplex must be an affine function, say $f(x)=a^tx+b$ in the simplex. This can be shown quite easily by induction on the dimension. (for a line it is trivial, for a triangle one can draw lines from the third point to the opposite side of the triangle, etc.)
Now for contradiction, suppose that there is a point $p\in X$ with $f(p)\neq a^tp+b$. Now take $x=p$, and let $y$ be some point in the interior of the simplex. The line between $x$ and $y$ intersects the simplex in a nonzero interval. Then statement (ii) for these $x$ and $y$ would imply that the function value inside the simplex is $\gamma f(x)+(1-\gamma)f(y)$, but this is then not equal to $a^t(\gamma x+(1-\gamma)y)+b$, and that is a contradiction with what we found before.
